# Парсинг строки Java

Tags: java

Пример строки:

```
{"bubma_vomba":"23782fhf3f3n893hg548745gn45g87h445,"lubma":0,"ider":275388012}
```

Нужно сделать так чтобы в новые переменные сохранить значения следующим образом

```
bubma_vomba = 23782fhf3f3n893hg548745gn45g87h445;
ider = 275388012;
```

вторая переменная lubma не нужна.

Как это осуществить?

Через две регулярки? Или тримом можно как-то обрезать?

Comment: s.split(",")[0].replaceAll("/"","") .split(":"). Это при условии, что порядок в строке не меняется.

Comment: Отсутствие кавычки - опечатка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это JSON строка, то в примере строки не хватает кавычек.
В примере так:

```
{"bubma_vomba":"23782fhf3f3n893hg548745gn45g87h445,"lubma":0,"ider":275388012}
```

должно быть так:

```
{"bubma_vomba":"23782fhf3f3n893hg548745gn45g87h445","lubma":0,"ider":275388012}
```

Вот еще один пример для парсинга JSON:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class Main {
private static String bubmaVomba;
private static long ider;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{\"bubma_vomba\":\"23782fhf3f3n893hg548745gn45g87h445\",\"lubma\":0,\"ider\":275388012}");

    bubmaVomba = obj.getString("bubma_vomba");
    ider = obj.getInt("ider");

    System.out.println("bubmaVomba = " + bubmaVomba);
    System.out.println("ider = " +  ider);
}
}
```

Соответствующую библиотеку для парсинга можно скачать от сюда: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub! at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:8)

Comment: Похожая проблема описана здесь: [ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560332/json-parsing-throws-error)

Возможно в classpath вашего проекта есть android.jar. Если вы пишите приложени для Android, то вы должны запускать его в эмуляторе или на реальном устройстве. (Что также значит, что вам необходим Activity вместо main()). В противном случае, вы должны удалить все связанное с Android из вашего classpath проекта и использовать стандартный Java SDK. Самый простой способ это создать новый Java (не Android) проект.

Comment: всё) именно в этой библиотеке и был косяк) писал я под windows,а библиотека по стандарту подключилась)

Answer (score 4):

Поскольку это похоже на [JSON](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), я рекомендую использовать библиотеку для парсинга JSON, например [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson):

```
@Test
public void ttt(){
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
            .create();
    String jsonString = "{\"bubma_vomba\":\"23782fhf3f3n893hg548745gn45g87h445\",\"lubma\":0,\"ider\":275388012}";
    BumbaVombaIder bvi = gson.fromJson(jsonString, BumbaVombaIder.class);
    System.out.print(bvi);
}

class BumbaVombaIder {
    private String bubmaVomba;
    private long ider;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(bubmaVomba).append(System.lineSeparator());
        sb.append(ider).append(System.lineSeparator());
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

> 23782fhf3f3n893hg548745gn45g87h445
>
> 275388012

Comment: прекрасно,только по ссылке,которую вы указали библиотека почему-то не работает под NetBeans,брал библиотеку вот отсюда https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.6.2/

Comment: что конкретно не работает?

Comment: как сохранить в переменные полученные значения? просто при попытке обратиться к приватным переменным он их зануляет (геттеры и сеттеры) не понятно.

Comment: уже целый час сижу голову ломаю

Comment: Что? Я не очень понял что вы написали. У вас после выполнения строчки `BumbaVombaIder bvi = gson.fromJson(jsonString, BumbaVombaIder.class);` в оъекте `bvi` поля инициализирвоаны нужными значениями? Куда вам их ещё сохранять нужно? "он их зануляет", кто кого "зануляет"?

Comment: @isuy у вас есть скайп? или просто объясню вот так : после выполнения фрагмента кода у меня выдается в консоль нужная мне информация. Но вот чтобы использовать её,к примеру : обратиться к переменным из другого класса и использовать их - никак не удается.

Comment: Ну то есть у вас все работает, вы просто не можете правильно связать ваши куски кода. Это уже отдельный вопрос. Чтобы обратиться к объекту `bvi` из другого класса, его нужно либо передать в конструктор другого класса, либо передать в метод другого класса, либо ещё как-то, я же не знаю что у вас там за код. Это и есть ваша задача, как программиста, уметь все это связать в единое целое.

Comment: просто вывести в две переменные два значения. В условиях задачи я это писал,что мне требуется две переменные к которым можно обратиться.

Comment: Я вот не понимаю, что вам мешает обратиться к переменным `String bubmaVomba; long ider;` в объекте `BumbaVombaIder bvi` ? Вам мешает `private`? Уберите его, сделайте геттеры или поменяйте `private` на `public`...

Comment: @isuy не получается